# Ввод нескольких строк с помощью функционального программирования на Python

Tags: python, функции, lambda

Задача состоит в том, чтобы считать несколько строк со стандартного ввода. Число строк задается в первой строке ввода (допустим N), а затем следует N строк, которые необходимо считать не используя for, if итд. Сделать это необходимо только с помощью элементов функционального программирования. Всю голову сломал, не могу сообразить как это сделать. Где-то на подсознании крутится, что нужно использовать range(N), но к чему это применить не пойму. Какие будут идеи?

Comment: что в вашем представлении является *"элементом функционального программирования"*?

Comment: к примеру, list comprehension содержит `for` и `if` формально, но вполне может рассматриваться *"элементом функционального программирования"* Haskell, который является чисто функциональным языком имеет похожую конструкцию с тем же именем.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
In [49]: N = 3

In [50]: a = list(map(lambda _: input('Input a string: '), range(N)))
Input a string: aaa
Input a string: bbb
Input a string: ccc

In [51]: print(a)
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

Comment: `map(lambda _:` некрасиво выглядит.

Answer (score 2):

Удобно [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) использовать, чтобы получить `N` строк из файла лениво:

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

N = int(next(sys.stdin))
lines = islice(sys.stdin, N)
```

Файл — это итератор над строками в Питоне.